# example of a functor in main

Tags: c++, functor

I have a class Bill, and I wrote this functor in this class

```
//functor 

    bool operator==(const Bill& other) const;

    void operator()(int x) { sumCost -= x; }
```

What I don't know, is how to use it in `main`.

Thanks for help!

Comment: Maybe you can find something useful here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/356950/c-functors-and-their-uses?rq=1

Comment: `Bill` itself is a functor. That means you can use an instance of `Bill` like a function.

Comment: @theunamedguy: Off-topic: Great avatar!

Answer (score 3):

Use it in the main will be the same as use in any other function:

```
int main()
{
    Bill b;
    b( 123 );
    return 0;
}
```